# Рекурсия работает только вглубь объекта

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Есть объект:

```
{
        nodeId: 0,
        nodes: [
            {
                nodeId: 1,
                nodes: [
                    {
                        nodeId: 2,
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                nodeId: 3
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        nodeId: 4,
                        nodes: [
                            {
                               nodeId: 5
                            },
                            {
                                nodeId: 6
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                nodeId: 7,
                nodes: [
                    {
                        nodeId: 8
                    },
                    {
                        nodeId: 9
                    },
                    {
                        nodeId: 10,
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                nodeId: 11
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Это пример, вложенность может быть любая. Каждый из вложенных объектов обязательно имеет nodeId.
Параметрами передается объект и ID, а функция должна найти и вернуть объект у которого nodeId === ID.
Вот что я сделал:

```
function findNodeByID(tree, id) {
        if (tree.nodeId === id) {
            return tree;
        } else if (tree.nodes && tree.nodes.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tree.nodes.length; i++) {
                return findNodeByID(tree.nodes[i], id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Но проблема в том что рекурсия идет только вглубь вложенных объектов. Например, при поиске объект со значением nodeId: 4, функция идет так:

```
nodeId - 0 -> nodeId - 1 -> nodeId - 2 -> nodeId - 3
```

и выходит. Как исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы сразу делаете в цикле return findNodeByID(tree.nodes[i], id), соответственно цикл просто не идет дальше первого элемента. Вариант исправления:

```js
const obj = {
  nodeId: 0,
  nodes: [{
      nodeId: 1,
      nodes: [{
        nodeId: 2,
        nodes: [{nodeId: 3}]
      }, {
        nodeId: 4,
        nodes: [{nodeId: 5}, {nodeId: 6}]
      }]
    }, {
      nodeId: 7,
      nodes: [{
          nodeId: 8
        }, {
          nodeId: 9,
          text: "I'm here!"
        }, {
          nodeId: 10,
          nodes: [{nodeId: 11}]
      }]
  }]
}
        
function findNodeByID(tree, id) {
    if (tree.nodeId === id) {
        return tree;
    } else if (tree.nodes && tree.nodes.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0, l = tree.nodes.length; i < l; ++i) {
            var foundNode = findNodeByID(tree.nodes[i], id);

            if (foundNode) {
                return foundNode;
            }
        }
    }
}
    
console.log(findNodeByID(obj, 9));
```

Comment: `find-found-found`